# Update offspring in nested tree mongoDB, node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, tree

Is there any way to update nested documents by id or some other field?

I use "[Full Tree in Single Document](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Trees+in+MongoDB#TreesinMongoDB-FullTreeinSingleDocument)" and don't know beforehand how deep nesting can go. Need to Update, for example, answer with {id:'104'}. I can do that via 'dot notation', but since I don't know the level (depth) of nesting I can't predict how long my `'comment.answers.answers....answers.'` can go.

Is there any way to directly find and update id:'104', or I still need to pass some kind of depth mark?

```
{
 title:'some title',
 comment:
     {
        id:'101'
        author:'Joe',
        text:'some comment',
        answers:
        [
            {
              id:'102'
              author:'Joe',
              text:'first answer to comment',
              answers:
                    [
                       {
                           id:'103'
                           author:'Done',
                           text:'first answer to first answer to comment',
                           answers:[]
                       },
                       {
                           id:'104'
                           author:'Bob',
                           text:'Second answer to first answer to comment',
                           answers:[]
                       }

                    ]

            },

            {
            },

            {
            },
        ]
     }
}
```

I use [The Node.JS MongoDB Driver](http://mongodb.github.com/node-mongodb-native/index.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short there's no really good way to do a query of this sort. There are a few options:

You can create a query with a long `$or` statement, specifying each of the possible nested locations for the document:

```
{ comment.id: 103, $or [
                        { comment.answers.id: 103 }, 
                        { comment.answers.answers.id: 103 },
                        { comment.answers.answers.answers.id: 103 } 
                       ] 
}
```

For more information about the [$or operator see the docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operators/#_S_or).

In truth, the better and more sustainable solution would be to use a different schema, where all comments and answers are stored in a flat array and then store information about the relationships between the comments in a `comments.parent` field. For example:

```
 { comment: [
           { id: 1 }
           { id: 2, parent: 1 }
          ] }
```

For additional options and a more in depth discussion of possible ways of modeling comment hierarchies, view the [Storing Comments Use Case](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/use-cases/storing-comments/) in the MongoDB documentation.

There are also a number of also strategies in the [Trees in MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Trees+in+MongoDB) that you might want to consider.

Comment: Thanks for feedback. I also think about different schema. The thing is that I use open source solution, which uses this type of data schema.

Answer (score 1):

I think you **should** store depth level of each node and then dynamically create queries.